# Why is more rep needed to create tag synonyms than to access 10k mod tools, on private beta sites?

Tags: discussion, privileges, private-beta, beta-sites

This doesn't really make any sense:

[image]

1,250 rep is needed to create tag synonyms, but only 1,000 rep is needed to access the 10k tools on **private** beta sites.

On **public** beta sites, as @Yannis pointed out in his [now deleted] answer, this is not the case.

I've written in red the rep needed on SO for the same privileges.

Should these be swapped round?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Tag synonyms will stay once beta is over, and your access will vanish - so early access to tag synonyms have strongest long-term effects than early access to moderation tools.

Comment: I hadn't considered it like that @Mołot - I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Note that I'm not sure my point of view is 100% right. Just wanted to add it for consideration. (No vote on this question from me, I know that I don't know)