# Why are some privilege rep requirements scaled differently for beta sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, beta-sites

[This MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/273585) clearly shows that reputation requirements for privileges are scaled down for sites in beta. This makes sense, as no one has had the opportunity to attain a high reputation count when a site is new.

However, I noticed today that not all privileges are scaled equally. Here are some examples from StackOverflow vs Engineering (Beta):

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Privilege        | SO     | Eng   | Scale (Eng/SO) |
------------------------------------------------------
| Trusted User     | 20,000 | 4,000 | 20%            |
| Cast Close Votes | 3,000  | 500   | 16.7%          |
| Full Editing     | 2,000  | 1,000 | 50%            |
| View Votes       | 1,000  | 750   | 75%            |
------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, some privileges are lowered more than others. In some cases, it actually changes the order of which privilege can be reached first.

I fully understand why rep requirements are scaled down overall, but why does the scale vary between privileges?

(Note: I found [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212890/273585) here on MSE, but the only response is speculation in the comments from one user, and it only addresses one particular privilege. I assume the community managers have a good reason for scaling many of the privileges differently, and I'd like to know what that reason is.)

Comment: My understanding is that the different order is due to the need. On a Beta, particularly early on, many questions will need to be closed, so close vote requirements are low to get more users quickly to the point that they can start having some moderation abilities.

Comment: @Catija That's been my assumption too, but I wanted to see if it is correct. It would be especially nice to hear from one of the community managers to confirm this.